# Is it possible to run awk Script from R Shiny App?

Tags: r, awk, shiny

I am new to both awk and Shiny App.

I wrote two programs:

1. an awk script (which creates a csv file)
2. an R Shiny App (which takes a csv file as input)

Currently, I run the awk script from my terminal by typing

```
awk -f scriptName.awk
```

Is there any possibility that lets me run this awk script from the Shiny App? That is, can I have the Shiny App initiate the above terminal command?

Many thanks in advance!

Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shell`, `shell.exec` or `system` (allows you to run a command from R).